# What is the Microsoft .NET Framework version refers to in Visual Studio "About Microsoft Visual Studio"

Tags: .net, visual-studio

What is the Microsoft .NET Framework version refers to in Visual Studio "About Microsoft Visual Studio"

Any documentation for the about page ?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework